# Changing App title - Google Play store issue

Tags: android, google-play

Trying to release a new version of my app on the play store - and I'm changing the App's name from the 'Store Listing' section. But I keep getting this error :

**You need to choose a different title for your app.**

**This one is already the title of tmp.xxxxxxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxx.**

I realized that the name I'm trying to enter is what is stored in the `@string/app_name` variable for the APK that is in release right now - is this why I'm getting the error? Will changing this name in the new APK fix the issue? Or am I missing out on something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, But you can set same or differ name from `@string/app_name` & its not affect your app, so don't worried about that.
But which Name you tried, that already taken by other so please add any extra phrase to your app name. Its only for show on Play Store.

Comment: I don't see the app name I'm trying to enter anywhere on the Play Store, why am I still getting that error??

Comment: you can set title in `Store Listing` Page, If your app name is `gif` then use `gif free`, because someone already set `gif` as name of app. you don't need to change in java code. you just need to change in `Store Listing` page

Comment: tmp.xxx.xxx is an unknown name in which, xxxx are an invisible character for us because of privacy of `Google Play Developer Console`.